# Run javascript before submitting a rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to run the following `html5 geolocation` javascript before submitting the form. Basically I'm after this process: the geolocation popup appears when submitting the form, the user clicks allow and then the form will be processed.

```
function getGeoLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
}

function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
}
```

And I'm trying to accomplish this via an `onclick` event from the form:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => "get" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true,
                   placeholder: "Enter keyword to search" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, onclick: "getGeoLocation();", :style => "display: none;" %>
<%end%>
```

But unfortunately nothing is happening, I'm receiving no errors under browser inspector as well! Any ideas on how to implement this?

**Update 1**

I'm also using autocomplete to submit the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "/search_suggestions",
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
            $('#search').closest("form").submit();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

If I use @Alex Kojin it redirects me to another form a have inside another tab.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to form's `submit` event, and there execute your code.

In case you use jquery:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getGeoLocation();
});
```

Manually submit the form in `setGeoCookie` method:

```
function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);

    $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Alex Kojin! Can you give me a few pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Geolocation is async, though.

Comment: @Alex Kojin ,  The geolocation popup appears but when I hit allow, it doesn't process the form, thus it doesn't redirect to the results!

Comment: Is it call `setGeoCookie` method? Try to call in the end  `$('#search form').submit();`

Comment: @Alex Kojin, if I put `$('form').submit` it processes another form and if I put `$('#search form').submit();` it doesn't do anything! weird I know!

Comment: @Alex Kojin please check update 1 for more info. I would appreciate your help, I'm kind of a newbie with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this with

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Obaiid Farooq!! Please check out update 1 for more info.